# How to implement an easy to use IIR-Filter in C/C++

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, c++

Edited:
I know there are some IIR filter implementation guides on the World Wide Web, however I can't find a simple guide on how to link simple PCM values to a digital filter. Most approaches are over-engineered and convert the files with the z-transform first.
In my first approach I followed [this tutorial](https://www.hs-schmalkalden.de/fileadmin/portal/Dokumente/Fakult%C3%A4t_ET/Personal/Roppel/Buch/Realisierung_Digitaler_Filter_in_C.pdf) (PDF, Sorry that it is in german).

### Directform II

```
std::vector<double> In // In is the vector that provides the PCM signal. In this scenario I assume that the sound signal is complete and does not need to be processed in real time.
std::vector<double> Out // Into the Vector Out then comes the finished PCM signal

double a[4], b[4], w[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};   
a[0] = 0.4142;  
a[1] = 0;  
b[0] = 0.2929;  
b[1] = 0.2929;  
b[2] = 0;

for(int x=0;x<y.size();x++){ 
        w[0] = In.at(x) + (a[0] * w[1]) + (a[1] * w[2]);    
        Out.at(x) = (b[0] * w[0]) + (b[1] * w[1]) + (b[2] * w[2]);   
        w[2] = w[1];   
        w[1] = w[0]; 
}
```

However, only absurdly high values come out, but I thought I would get PCM values between -1 and 1.

Afterwards I tried to write [this formula](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/6ff74c707f155387d5590c8ed3059679a20abdd7)  simply in code form, here the frequency response unfortunately shows a completely different behavior than what I expected (I checked the coefficients with Matlab).

Here is [the second try](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response):

### Direct Form I (I think)

```
 b[0] = 1.0;
 b[1] = -2.494956002;
 b[2] = 2.017265875;
 b[3] = -0.522189400;

 a[0] = 0.049922035;
 a[1] = -0.095993537;
 a[2] = 0.050612699;
 a[3] = -0.004408786;
for (int k = 0; k < Out.size(); k++) {    
        if (i - 3 < 0) { //I came up with these three if queries to get around the recursion of the first three PCM values. I know this is not the most elegant way, but I thought it would give me at least a rough idea of the IIR filter
            if (i - 2 < 0) {
                if (i - 1 < 0) {
                    Out.at(i) = 1 / a[0] * (b[0] * In->at(i) + 0 + 0 + 0 - 0 - 0 - 0);
                }
                else {
                    Out.at(i) = 1 / a[0] * (b[0] * In->at(i) + b[1] * In->at(i - 1) + 0 + 0 - a[1] * In->at(i - 1) - 0 - 0);
                }
            }
            else {
                Out.at(i) = 1 / a[0] * (b[0] * In->at(i) + b[1] * In->at(i - 1) + b[2] * In->at(i - 2) + 0 - a[1] * In->at(i - 1) - a[2] * In->at(i - 2) - 0);
            }
        }
        else { //This line of code is the heart of the code:
            Out.at(i) = 1 / a[0] * (b[0] * In->at(i) + b[1] * In->at(i - 1) + b[2] * In->at(i - 2) + b[3] * In->at(i - 3) - a[1] * In->at(i - 1) - a[2] * In->at(i - 2) - a[3] * In->at(i - 3));
        }

    }
```

I thought Direct Form I and II only differed in performance, so I didn't care about the form for now. As I said, my goal is to process already stored PCM samples.

Comment: Your code no comments, you don't provide a reference for where you got this idea from, you variable naming is highly questionable and you don't show where your filter coefficients come from.  This looks like botched Direct Form II implementation but without more info, this is hard to tell. You SHOULD care about the form. DF II actually produces "absurdly high values" for state variables of certain filters. If you don't want that, don't use DF II

Comment: In addition to Hilmar's concerns, in your second block of code, only the first line works. Everything else is hidden behind the start of a comment `/*` (and the `for` only executes the one line: ` In->at(k) = Out.at(k);`.  Please address these concerns [*by editing your question*](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/83541/edit) and ping me and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: @PeterK. I edited the question, do you think it is okay now?

Comment: Much better! I've revised it a little.

Comment: It is much more recommended to use biquad cascaded form, rather than a direct form if your filter order is high.

Comment: @Hilmar What exactly do you mean by state variables? With me, I also have these high values with the output signal. I thought I should still be in the range between 1 and -1 there?